# Cannot find symbol variable GoogleAuthUtil after updating to Google Play services 9.0.0

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-plus-signin, google-signin

Compilation error:

```
Error:(xx, xx) error: package com.google.android.gms.auth does not exist
Error:(xx, xx) error: cannot find symbol variable GoogleAuthUtil
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

GoogleAuthUtil has moved to the -auth SDK split in the Google Play services 9.0+ SDK.

If you need to access the REST API on Android, include the -auth split in your build.gradle file:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.0'
```

Otherwise, we recommend migrating your app to the [Google Sign-In API](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in) to incorporate the latest improvements in security and user experience into your app.

Please read the migration guide:
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/migration-guide#migrate_from_the_googleauthutil_id_token_flow

And a blogpost for more details:
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/05/improving-security-and-user-experience.html